# Function in c using the struct

Tags: c

i have to write a function in c using the struct that want to return the average between all the min values of multiple list of students , for example we have 2 lists :

```
student_0 has :(19,20,18,14);
student_1 has :(15,30,29,19);
```

i have to pick from s0 the min votes and put the first value in a sum of the all min values and do the average : (take the example up) 14+15 / 2 (2 the counter of the total_min_values);

My code is this :

```
struct studente{
    unsigned int *voti;
    unsigned int voti_size;
};

float mean_of_min(struct studente *lst, int lst_size) {
    int minimo = lst->voti[0];
    
    float somma = 0;
    float media = 0;
    int  conta = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < lst_size; i++) {
        for (int j = 1;j< lst->voti_size ; j++){
            if (minimo <= lst[i].voti[j] ){
                somma+=minimo;
                conta++;
            }
            if (minimo > lst[i].voti[j]){
                minimo = lst->voti[j];
                somma+=minimo;
                conta++;
            }
            media= somma / conta;
        }
    }
    
    return media;
}
```

this function works but not properly , any idea how to fix or improve my function  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please indent your code when you submit a question it will be easier for other to understand your code.

Then, the following code doesn't work as you expext

```
for (int i = 0; i < lst_size; i++) {
    for (int j = 1;j< lst->voti_size ; j++){
        if (minimo <= lst[i].voti[j] ){
            somma+=minimo;
            conta++;
        }
```

For instance if you have 2 students with the value `(5,4,3)` and `(2,5,1)`, your output will be `4+3+2+1 = 15` where you'd expect `3+1=4`

Your algoritm is wrong you have to get the minimum of a student, not add values every time your value is below the lowest value so far.

I give you this pseudo code, I let you translate it in C so that you understand better

```
sum = 0
For student in students:
 | min = student.votes[0]
 | For vote in student.votes
 | | IF vote < min:
 | | | min = vote
 | sum += min
```

Please also note that your computation of mean has to be done outside the loop to output correct values.

Finally this part makes no sense in your algorithm.

```
 if (minimo > lst[i].voti[j]){
                minimo = lst->voti[j];
                somma+=minimo;
                conta++;
            }
```

Next time when you have a such exercice write an algorithm in pseudocode on paper and run it manually to check that you find the desired outputs. Only start coding then.

Comment: I have understood what did you say , but the problem is that the vote its not always < than the min value , could be exists a vote > than the min picked

Comment: It is even difficult to me to understand the struct argument , not the sintax but how it works with an input .

Comment: You want to sum the minimum of EACH student as I did. Hence, you always add the minimum vote (which is NOT the global minimum i.e. the minimum of all students)